# How to insert data if not exists in mysql?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am learning PHP.
I would like to insert data in MySql Database only when there is no record. Or, if any record exists I would like to update it.
How can I do that?

Comment: where is the code that you tried to insert the data?

Answer (score 3):

You are actually looking for `UPSERT/MERGE` statement in `MySQL`; which is nothing but [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). A sample example would be like below

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Check the documentation for more information on the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started. But please give us code to work with next time!

```
$result = mysql_query(MySqlQuery);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

//if a record or records exist...
if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code for MYSQLI :

```
$query= $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE column = `$var`");
$count= $result->fetch_row();
if($count <= 0){
$insert="INSERT INTO table VALUES('".$var."')";
$dbh->mysqli_query($insert);
echo .$var "Inserted";
}else{
echo "Variable already found in column";
}
```